# Clip SVG text to width of rectangle in a D3 treemap

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, treemap

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to restrict the width of a text label than using a clip path.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for with regard to labeling: [treemap](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/treemap.html):

[image]

Notice that the labels get truncated by the boundaries of the containing tiles.

That particular example is implemented using `<div>` tags, which have this behaviour by default.  But I'm using SVG `<rect>` and I'm hoping there is a more straight-forward way of doing this than a separate clip path defining another rect shape.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap each `<rect>` element in an `<svg>` element of the same width/height. By default [overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#OverflowProperty) is hidden on inner `<svg>` elements.