# D3 JS Drilldown Treemap overlapping <text>

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using Mike Bostock Drilldown / Zoomable Treemap.

**Link: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/**

I did some customizations but the core still the same.

As follow the image bellow, when the zoom finds "micro-rects", the text is overlapped

[Overflowed Text Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8eNK.png)

I tried to fix it getting the height/width of my text element and comparing it to the height/width of the rect.

```
        d3.select(texto).attr("display", function (d) {
                if(d.width > 10 && d.height > 10){
                    if (this.getBBox().height > d.height && this.getBBox().width > d.width)
                        return "none";
                    else return "inline";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "none";
                }
                });
```

The problem is, when the transition happens, the rect got dynamic size, getting much higher than the original size.

I cant figure out a work around.

Comment: You could truncate the text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023417/clip-svg-text-to-width-of-rectangle-in-a-d3-treemap

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Following your suggestion, I implemented the a trucante function. The bigger problem is, how deeper I get in the treemap, less efectiveness the function have. All this truncate functions uses height / width / x or y to compare the width of the label, but as I said, when the transition happens, the rect got dynamic size differently of the final form.

Comment: This approach works when the treemap changes (as you can see in the linked demo). What do you want it to do as you zoom in?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff your example have a totaly diferent structure of data ( The nodes are built by divs ). I'm using Bostock structure bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap. which uses g elements to build the treemap. I chose the Bostock because it does drilldown when it zooms in and out.